# Rows not lining up correctly using bootstrap and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularfire

Right now I'm using AngularJS (angularfire) to retrieve data from firebase, after some searching I found some example code that uses ng-switch to switch rows so I can have a grid of books (I'm writing a little library app).

For some reason when I run it I get the first row to look ok, then the next row shows 1 book, then the remaining seem to look right. (3 per row)

[image]

This is the "logic" I'm using>

```
<div ng-repeat="book in filteredBooks = (books | orderByPriority | filter:search)">
      <span ng-switch on="$index % 3">
        <div ng-class="row" ng-switch-when="0">
          <div class="col-lg-4" src="#" ng-show="filteredBooks[$index+0]">
          {{$index % 3}} -- {{$index}}
            <img src="http://covers.openlibrary.org/b/isbn/{{filteredBooks[$index+0].isbn}}-M.jpg"/> <br />
            <small><em>{{filteredBooks[$index+0].title}}</em></small><br />
            <small>ISBN: {{filteredBooks[$index+0].isbn.length}} -- {{filteredBooks[$index+0].isbn}} </small><br />
            <small>Dewey Decimal: {{filteredBooks[$index+0].class}} </small><br /> 
            <form name="checkoutForm">
               <blockquote>
                  <b>Who:{{checkout.name}}</b>
               </blockquote>
             <input ng-model="checkout.name" />
             <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
             </form>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4" src="#" ng-show="filteredBooks[$index+1]">
          {{$index+1 % 3}} -- {{$index}}
            <img src="http://covers.openlibrary.org/b/isbn/{{filteredBooks[$index+1].isbn}}-M.jpg"/> <br />
            <small><em>{{filteredBooks[$index+1].title}}</em></small><br />
            <small>ISBN: {{filteredBooks[$index+1].isbn.length}} -- {{filteredBooks[$index+1].isbn}} </small><br />
            <small>Dewey Decimal: {{filteredBooks[$index+1].class}} </small><br />
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4" src="#" ng-show="filteredBooks[$index+2]">
          {{$index+2 % 3}} -- {{$index}}
            <img src="http://covers.openlibrary.org/b/isbn/{{filteredBooks[$index+2].isbn}}-M.jpg"/> <br />
            <small><em>{{filteredBooks[$index+2].title}}</em></small><br />
            <small>ISBN: {{filteredBooks[$index+2].isbn.length}} -- {{filteredBooks[$index+2].isbn}} </small><br />
            <small>Dewey Decimal: {{filteredBooks[$index+2].class}} </small><br />
          </div>
        </div>
      </span>
    </div>
```

Based on the 0--0, 1--0, 2--0... stuff, I can tell that it's doing the rows right (I think) it just doesn't seem to be lining up right.

Can someone point me to what is going on and/or tell me how to fix it? I see that we are getting a new row, but I can't figure out why it's not got the next two books in the same row as itself.

Another potentially related question is what do the numbers with the col-lg-# mean?

I try different variations on them, and I might see a little difference in display but there is always still something *weird* going on, not just a straightforward grid.

(I've tried md/lg, and 2,3,4,5,6 for the different #'s but don't see anything helping overall)

Comment: Why `ng-class="row"`? `col-lg-*` is Bootstrap grid markup. You should make yourself familiar: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Wow....removing NG- from that worked..... I feel dumb, I think somewehere in one of the examples I saw ng-class="row" and was using that. Thank you so much! (if you answer I'll mark it as solved....so weird). Also I have looked at the bootstrap css grid stuff quite a bit, still just don't really get the #'s stuff.

Comment: In `col-lg-4`, for example, `lg` indicates the applicable screen size range, and `4` indicates that 4 of 12 columns will be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that `ng-class=` should simply be `class=`.

It happens to all of us. :-)